# Unable to fix space issue in Home Page

Tags: wordpress, padding

I am creating my new travel website https://airlineticketsbestprice.com. So I have downloaded a travel theme and updated my content.

Also, I have add some more section in home page (example call to action, popular destinations, subscribe newsletter and latest aticle ). But as I have noticed that there are much more space between these section, so I am trying to fix this through CSS file but issue still remain.

So could you please tell me which file and CSS file class should I change.

Kindly help me to send exact Css class file code.

Thanks

Comment: Which more space you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In your style.ccs you might change this:

```
p {
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

to this:

```
p {
margin-bottom: [any number]em;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

or

```
p {
padding-bottom: [any number]em;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Please note, that it will effect all your paragraphs on your website.
Or if you don't want to have any space after a paragraph use the *Shift+Enter* combo.